# Why if I use a continuous character in a html file it overrides the margin of the page?

Tags: html

I was working in Dreamweaver, I opened a div tag and inserted a same character several times, like this: `ffffffffff`, I use it to fill it with some text, but I noticed that if I copy and paste a lot of times, like this: `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`, eventually the right margin is overridden, it does not work.

For example I expected something like this:

(webpage example, div container)

```
 ================== 
|ffffffffffffffffff|                 
|ffffffffffffffffff|
|ffffffffffffffffff|
```

but I get this:

```
====================
|fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff 
|
|
```

So eventually I have to scroll the window to the right in order to see the whole text. The strange thing is that if I use a text with spaces, or even the same `fffffffffff` with spaces between, like this: `ffffff ffffff fffff`, it displays correctly and the right margin works as expected.

```
   ===================
   |fff fff fffffffff|
   |ffff fffffff ffff|
   |ffffffffffff ffff|
```

I did not find any answer searching about this strange behavior, any help will be very much appreciated.

Note: Btw, the same thing happens no matter what editor I use, for example with sublime, text editor, etc.

Comment: Because `fffff...` is one word and the browser by default does not break words in order to wrap. Remian8959's answer is correct: it tells the browser to break words mid-word so that the characters correctly wrap.

Comment: **If `fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` is one word, browser don't know about it. So Its override your view**. And I never know this kind of word having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file, make a new style and put `word-wrap: break-word;` in it. Use that for the paragraph you want that to happen. It allows the browser to *break* a word as the code suggests. More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break).

The reason that you get expected results with spaces is because the default word-wrap style is to break by words, or in other words, characters separated by spaces (and some other stuff may be).